# mean for subsets using survey

Tags: r, survey

I have two variables "c" and "q" in a data.frame. "c" is a number between zero and one (a level of poverty) and "q" indicate if the household (or subject) is poor with 1 or non-poverty with zero.
How can I calculate the mean of "c" only of the poor households (q=1).

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATtXH.png)

Important detail: I have a database for a coutry and I want this result for regions.
I am using the `svyby` like this:

`svyby( ~q , ~region , design = base2015_pos , na.rm=TRUE, svytotal)`

so in that way the R give me the number of poor by region and I don't need this now. I need the mean of a subset (see image above) by region.

`structure(list(domicilio = c(11000015001, 11000015003, 11000015004), agua = c(0, 0, 6), ind_agua = c(0, 0, 1), esgoto = c(1, 1, 6), ind_cond_sanitaria = c(1, 1, 1), lixo = c(0, 0, 0), ind_lixo = c(0, 0, 0), luz = c(0, 0, 0), ind_iluminacao = c(0, 0, 0), ativos = c(0, 0, 0), ind_ativos = c(0, 0, 0), emprego = c(0, 0, 0), ind_emprego = c(0, 0, 0), renda = c(0, 0, 0), ind_renda = c(0, 0, 0), casa = c(1, 1, 0), ind_riqueza = c(1, 1, 0), anos = c(0, 0, 0), ind_estudo = c(0, 0, 0), ler = c(0, 0, 0), ind_alfabetizado = c(0, 0, 0), peso = c(270, 270, 270), sexo = c(0, 1, 1), uf = c("11", "11", "11"), v4609 = c("001772940", "001772940", "001772940"), v4617 = c(110001, 110001, 110001), v4618 = c(1, 1, 1), pre_wgt = c(200, 200, 200), one = c(1L, 
1L, 1L), region = c("1", "1", "1"), c = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), q = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("domicilio", "agua", "ind_agua", "esgoto", "ind_cond_sanitaria", "lixo", "ind_lixo", "luz", "ind_iluminacao","ativos", "ind_ativos", "emprego", "ind_emprego", "renda", "ind_renda", "casa", "ind_riqueza", "anos", "ind_estudo", "ler", "ind_alfabetizado","peso", "sexo", "uf", "v4609", "v4617", "v4618", "pre_wgt", "one", "region", "c", "q"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  You should check out [ask].  In the meantime it would help us help you included a sample of your data frame using `dput(data.frame)` and pasting the resultant code into your question.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I did, but I don't know how paste the huge resultant code editing my question.

Comment: `dput(head(data.frame, x))` where x is the number of rows you wish to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# complex sample survey design
library(survey)

# your data.frame
x <- structure(list(domicilio = c(11000015001, 11000015003, 11000015004), agua = c(0, 0, 6), ind_agua = c(0, 0, 1), esgoto = c(1, 1, 6), ind_cond_sanitaria = c(1, 1, 1), lixo = c(0, 0, 0), ind_lixo = c(0, 0, 0), luz = c(0, 0, 0), ind_iluminacao = c(0, 0, 0), ativos = c(0, 0, 0), ind_ativos = c(0, 0, 0), emprego = c(0, 0, 0), ind_emprego = c(0, 0, 0), renda = c(0, 0, 0), ind_renda = c(0, 0, 0), casa = c(1, 1, 0), ind_riqueza = c(1, 1, 0), anos = c(0, 0, 0), ind_estudo = c(0, 0, 0), ler = c(0, 0, 0), ind_alfabetizado = c(0, 0, 0), peso = c(270, 270, 270), sexo = c(0, 1, 1), uf = c("11", "11", "11"), v4609 = c("001772940", "001772940", "001772940"), v4617 = c(110001, 110001, 110001), v4618 = c(1, 1, 1), pre_wgt = c(200, 200, 200), one = c(1L, 
1L, 1L), region = c("1", "1", "1"), c = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), q = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("domicilio", "agua", "ind_agua", "esgoto", "ind_cond_sanitaria", "lixo", "ind_lixo", "luz", "ind_iluminacao","ativos", "ind_ativos", "emprego", "ind_emprego", "renda", "ind_renda", "casa", "ind_riqueza", "anos", "ind_estudo", "ler", "ind_alfabetizado","peso", "sexo", "uf", "v4609", "v4617", "v4618", "pre_wgt", "one", "region", "c", "q"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

# your survey.design (this is not the correct svydesign statement, please follow the directions specific to your data set)
y <- svydesign( ~ 1 , data = x , weights = ~ pre_wgt )

# your desired subset
z <- subset( y , q == 1 )

# your desired mean
svyby( ~ c , ~ region , z , svymean )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(df$c, by=list(df$q), FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility. To illustrate, create a dataset per your parameters:

```
set.seed(787)
dat.a <-runif(n=10,min=0,max=1)
dat.b <-rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.5)
dat.1 <-data.frame(matrix(c(dat.a, dat.b), ncol=2, nrow=10))
colnames(dat.1) <-c("c","q")

dat.1
            c q
1  0.35326234 1 
2  0.45277055 0
3  0.29505270 0
4  0.78723105 1
5  0.95915348 1
6  0.17505284 0
7  0.79693672 0
8  0.01648420 1
9  0.02706417 0
10 0.93996311 1
```

Now subset by extracting all rows that match q=1 and compute mean for column c in resulting output:

```
dat.1.subset <-dat.1[dat.1$q==1,]

mean(dat.1.subset$c)
[1] 0.6112188
```

Comment: I did, but after that I tried this:
`svyratio( ~subset$c, ~subset$q , ~region , design = base2015_pos , na.rm=TRUE, svytotal)`

and he give me this:
`Error in if (separate) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (separate) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`



thanks

Comment: Jose, if you tried my recommendation and it worked (or didn't), please advise. Meantime, I'm not able to comment on the update you present without data and code.

Comment: Thanks @JPP.
I didn't know how to create a subset mean.